# writing expression in vector form

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the following expression:

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N} -k^{(i)} (k^{(i)})^T[\frac{e^{-a^Tk^{(i)}}}{(1+e^{-a^Tk^{(i)}})^2}]$

where $k^{(i)}, a \in R^n$.

I was wondering if there is a way to put this in vector form (getting rid of the summation and using matrices). $N$ could be big and when coding I don't want to run a loop with $N$ iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options you might like. Option 1: define 
$$
v^{(i)} = \frac{\sqrt{e^{-a^Tk^{(i)}}}}{1 + e^{-a^T k^{(i)}}} k^{(i)}.
$$
Then your expression is equal $-VV^T$, where $V$ is the matrix whose columns are $v^{(1)},\dots,v^{(N)}$.

Option 2: define $D$ to be the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries 
$$
d^{(i)} = \frac{{e^{-a^Tk^{(i)}}}}{(1 + e^{-a^T k^{(i)}})^2}.
$$
Then your expression is equal to $-KDK^T$, where $K$ is the matrix whose columns are $k^{(1)},\dots,k^{(N)}$.

---

The vector of values $d^{(1)},\dots,d^{(N)}$ could itself be computed without a loop. In particular, compute
$$
a^T K = \pmatrix{a^T k^{(1)}& \cdots & a^Tk^{(N)}},
$$
and then apply the function $f(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{(1 + e^{-x})^2}$ to each entry of the row-vector $a^TK$.